# Date format in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

```
strOLD = Convert.ToString(this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);
strNEW = Convert.ToString(this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].EditedFormattedValue);
```

on cell validating the format of old  date i.e value and new value after the click edit 
formatted value are differnt.One
So even if the dates are same it shows value has been updated.
How to make format of these two date same so that when dates are same it shows equal
else update has been made.

Comment: Are you sure of the `asp net` `web-app` tags ?

Comment: What database are you connecting to?

Comment: database is in sqlserver

Comment: Could you cast them to a DateTime, then use ToString() on the DateTime objects to make them uniform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is related to winforms(*you mention cell validating and also EditedFormattedValue*), you can set the format for display of the values in the TextBoxColumn by setting the `DefaultCellStyle.Format`

```
yourcolumm.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

Also you should compare it with `.FormattedValue` which would as per the Format specified for the column (Please compare as DateTime objects as that would make sense)

Comment: Its already done.Then also it picks full date i.e date and time.

Comment: when date is shown in the gridbox it is yyyy/mm/dd but when it is picked while cell validating it takes the value with time as stored in the datebase

Comment: There is DateTime type col in `DataGridView`, is it your custom column or TextBoxColumn?

Comment: it is a normal column but data stored in this col is of type datetime not string.